# Interrogating Java source code

Tags: java, security, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a Java source code that I need to interrogate and apply security policies [for e.g. applying CWE]
 I have couple of ideas, for starters using AST and then travel thru the tree. Others include using regular expression.
Are there any options other than AST or regex that I could use for such process.

Answer (score 2):

An AST is a good choice, much better than regular expressions.

There are numerous Java parsers available. [ANTLR's java grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) is one example.

You can also adapt the source code of the [`javac` compiler from OpenJDK.](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/)

Some static analysis tools like [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) support user-defined rules that would allow you to perform many checks without a lot of work.

Comment: thanks. I definitely forgot ANTLR. I thought of extending PMD to include my own policies, but hesitant to learn PMD. Anyway, will inspect all of these. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Many static source code analysis (SCA) tools use a collection of regular expressions to detect code that maybe vulnerable.  There are many [SCA tools for Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-analyzers) and I don't know the best open source one off hand.  I can tell you that [Coverity](http://www.coverity.com/) makes the best Java SCA tool that i have used,  its much more advanced than just regular expressions as it can also detect  race conditions.

What I can tell you is that this approach is going to produce a lot of false positives and false negatives.   The CWE system indexes HUNDREDS of different vulnerabilities and covering all of them is completely and totally impossible.

Comment: I agree. trying to implement all of CWE might end up in lotta false pos/negs.. but i guess its still ok because its ok to have then not have one. i will look into covierty

Comment: @VibeofBoston your going to get false pos/neg with the most simple of cve's like sql injection.  No tool (not even Coverty)  covers even 5% of all cwe's.  I don't think any tool can get much more than that.   For some vuls have you to do manual code analysis.

Comment: actually, if you take any source code and try to implement pieces of CWE, yes you will probably won't get the correct results. but if someone provides meta information like what to look for, patterns, then it sort gets easier to implement..

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of pre-existing tools that do some or all of what you are asking for. Some on the source code level, and some by parsing the byte code.

Have a look at
 - [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)
 - [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)
 - [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)

All of these are extendable in one way or another, so you can probably get them to check what you want to check in addition to the many standard checks they have

Comment: actually i am already aware of checkstyle, findbugs, pmd. what I intent to do is little more complicated [but maybe very well supported by these tools]. I am planning to apply security policies from CWE.

Answer (score 0):

You either want to get an existing static analysis tool that focuses on the vulnerabilities of interest to you, or you want to get a tool with strong foundations for building custom analyses.

Just parsing to ASTs doesn't get you a lot of support for doing analysis. You need to know what symbols mean where encountered (e.g., scopes, symbol tables, type resolution), and you often need to know how information flows [(inheritance graphs, calls graphs, control flows, data flows)](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/FlowAnalysis.html) across the software elements that make up the system.   Tools like ANTLR don't provide this; they are *parser* generators.

A tool foundation having this information available for Java is our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) and its [Java Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/JavaFrontEnd.html).